# How to return only the first date of a sequence of dates?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, jobs

I'm breaking my head trying to create a query for the following situation: I'm using an oracle database, I have a job that always runs at 00 o'clock, so I will fetch the beginning of a user's recess, in the example below we see how are the dates.

```
DATE_RECESS    | USER_ID 
---------------------------
22/09/21       |    1
21/09/21       |    1
20/09/21       |    1
19/09/21       |    1
18/09/21       |    1
```

I will need to notify him missing 10 days to the beginning of the recess, this notification will be sent only 1 time ...

So, looking at these dates with example, I should send 1 single notification on 08/09/21, I should not notify on the other days, only on the first day.

I can't send notification for every day, I should have some return just missing 10 days to start. Summarizing there's my doubt:

How to create a query, (which will be executed by a job that will run every day), and that does not bring result every day? Only when the first date is found?

---

For me to know what dates are missing 10 days I will take as base my current date, today + 10 days... if I find any date in this period then there I have a recess, but the return of the query should only bring something if it is date is the day 18/09/21, because there is beginning of the recess ... if today + 10 fall on the 19th I will bring nothing, because there will be the second day ...

Comment: Do the dates in the table change? Any updates, inserts or deletions?

Comment: How is the question `java`-related? --- Looks like an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1;` should do the trick.

Comment: How do you know 10 days are missing?

Comment: hi @GordonLinoff, I updated the description showing how I'll find the records that are 10 days from the start of the recess.

Comment: hi @AndiCover, The dates are not changed, are fixed, I updated the description showing how I will find the records that are 10 days from the beginning of the recess.